# Transforming Date Formats in cXML document

Tags: xml, date, xslt, time, timestamp

I'm currently working on a cXML integration project and have run into an issue with timestamp and date/time formats in my project.

Our system current is able to generate all dates/times, but does so in the format "9/2/2020 1:59 PM".

How can I use an XSLT to transform the dates times into the formats needed below?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHS7w.png)

""

variable timestamp= Needs to be in format

2020-09-01T12:00:00-05:00

And ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Sorry but is your current format DD/MM/YYYY Or MM/DD/YYYY?

Comment: MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM P

Comment: Where is "-05:00" supposed to come from?

Comment: "-05:00" can be static text.